# How to use Repaint in AchartEngine Bar Graph Android

Tags: android, bar-chart, achartengine, repaint

I have a list where the values will be updated for every 15 sec,, I want to repaint the bar graph but confused where to call that, here is my code pls help me in doing that.

```
public GraphicalView createIntentAll() {
    String[] titles = new String[] { "Amount"};
    double[] d= new double[a2.size()] ;
    for(int i=0;i<a2.size();i++){
    d[i] = a2.get(i);
    }

    List<double[]> values = new ArrayList<double[]>();
    values.add(d);  
        System.out.println("=========="+values.get(0));
        int[] colors = new int[] { Color.parseColor("#77c4d3")};
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = buildBarRenderer(colors);
        renderer.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
        setChartSettings(renderer, "Monthly Details", "Months", "Earnings", 0.5,
                12.5, 0, yaxis, Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK);
        renderer.setXLabels(1);
        renderer.setYLabels(10);

        for(int i =0;i<y2.size();i++){
            renderer.addXTextLabel(i+1, y2.get(i));
            System.out.println("==y2==="+y2.get(i));
        }
        int length = renderer.getSeriesRendererCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            SimpleSeriesRenderer seriesRenderer = renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(i);
            seriesRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        }
gv = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(getActivity(), buildBarDataset(titles, values), renderer,Type.DEFAULT);
 LinearLayout chartContainer = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(
        R.id.chart_container);


 chartContainer.addView(gv);
 gv.repaint();
        return null;
}
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you modify the contents of your dataset, you must call `gv.repaint()` in order to have the chart be updated.

Comment: I am facing the same problem..where you added gv.rePaint();?